# Am I using states correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app with a homepage that shows a list of things. Each thing has a type. In the nav, there are selectors corresponding to each thing type. Clicking one of these selectors causes the home controller to filter the things shown to those of the selected type. As such, I see the selectors as corresponding to states of the home page.

Now, I'd like to map each of these states to a url route: `myapp.com/home` loads the home page in default (unfilitered) state, `myapp.com/home/foo` opens the home page with the `foo`-type selector activated, and switching from there to `myapp.com/home/bar` switches to the `bar`-filtered state ***without reloading the page***.

It's that last bit - triggering "state" changes without reloading the page, that's been particularly tricky to figure out. There are numerous SO/forum questions on this topic but none have quite hit the spot, so I'm wondering if I'm thinking about this in the wrong way: Should I be thinking of these "states" as states at all? Is there a simpler approach?

Also, I'm open to using either `ngRoute` or `ui.router` - is there anything about one or the other that might make it simpler to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ui-router, you can approach it like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    controller: "HomeController",
    templateUrl: "home.html"
    // .. other options if required
  })
  .state('home.filtered', {
    url: "/{filter}",
    controller: "HomeController",
    templateUrl: "home.html"
    // .. other options if required
  })
```

This creates a filtered state as a child of the home state and means that you can think of the URL to the filtered state as `/home/{filter}`. Where `filter` is a state parameter that can then be accessed using `$stateParams`.

Since you don't want to switch views, you inject $stateParams into your controller, watch `$stateParams.filter`, and react to it how you wish.

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return $stateParams.filter }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // handle it
});
```